# Gridview row updating error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a gridview and have modified it following this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036.aspx#Y3473
to allow bulk updates. Whenever I try to update a row in this loop:

```
For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If IsRowModified(r) Then GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
    Next
```

I get this error:

> You have specified that your update command compares all values on
>   SqlDataSource 'ARDataSource', but the dictionary passed in for
>   oldValues is empty.  Pass in a valid dictionary for update or change
>   your mode to OverwriteChanges.

I have no idea what this could be caused by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ConflictDetection` from `CompareAllValues` to `OverwriteChanges`.
[SqlDataSource.ConflictDetection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.conflictdetection.aspx)

Comment: X.X I probably should've tried that first. I just assumed it was something else since I've used gridviews/datasources before and never ran into that before.